# Value not storing in powershell variable

Tags: variables, powershell, datatable

I am calling a PS function while passing it a string and a datatable variable. I want to extract all items in the `datatable` and store them in an object.

Here is my code from my script:

```
Function myFunc
{
    param ($id, $dt)
    $data = $dt | where-object ($_.ID -eq $ID)
}

$myVar = myFunc -id "stringID" -dt myDataTable
```

When this runs my `data` variable stays empty.

I have a breakpoint placed at the end of my project so I can try and play with the values. When I try and re-create the issue it works:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> $abc = $myDataTable | where-object {$_.ID -eq $ID}

[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> $abc


ID          : //info here
Location    : //info here
Managedr    : //info here
```

It just will not work in my actual script.

Comment: For one thing your function doesn't return anything, because you capture all output in the variable `$data`. Also, is the lack of `$` in `-dt myDataTable` a typo in your question or in your actual script? And why do you have that parameter in the first place, if you're not using it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes there was a typo in my original question. My function should read `$data = $dt | where-object ($_.ID -eq $ID)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function runs in it's own scope, and the scope and all variables created in the scope are disposed when the function exits. Functions should return data, which you assign to variables in the local scope, like this:

```
Function myFunc
{
    param ($id, $dt)
    $myDataTable | where-object ($_.ID -eq $ID)
}

$myVar = myFunc -id "stringID" -dt myDataTable
```

Comment: Johnrad just be aware that I think you need to change the line to `$dt | where-object ($_.ID -eq $ID)` since there is no variable called `$myDataTable` in the scope of the function